# Check if multiple properties either all exist or are all missing

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I have an object of the following form:

```
const obj = {
  foo: {},
  bar: {},
  baz: {}
};
```

The object has to conform to the following rules:

- The property `foo` must be given.
- The properties `bar` and `baz` are both optional.
- If `bar` is given, then also `baz` must be given.

It is pretty easy to check for `foo`:

```
if (!obj.foo) {
  throw new Error('Foo is missing.');
}
```

How can I check for the other properties, in an elegant way? Of course I could do something such as:

```
if ((obj.bar && !obj.baz) || (!obj.bar && obj.baz)) {
  throw new Error('Bar or baz is missing.');
}
```

But this doesn't scale well. What if I do not have to check two properties, but 20, which either all have to be there, or none of them?

Ideally, I even would like the error message to exactly specify which one is missing (it's enough if it reports the first one).

I already thought of this (which effectively means: If at least one of the optional ones is given, check if any of them are missing):

```
if (obj.bar || obj.baz) {
  if (!obj.bar) {
    throw new Error('Var is missing.);
  }
  if (!obj.baz) {
    throw new Error('Baz is missing.);
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to make an array of the properties that need to all be together, and then use `reduce` on it to get the number of found properties. If the result is 0 or the length of the array, it's valid, else it's invalid.

```js
const together = ['bar', 'baz', 'buzz'];
const validate = obj => {
  if (!obj.foo) return false;
  const togPropCount = together.reduce((a, prop) => a + (prop in obj), 0);
  return togPropCount === 0 || togPropCount === together.length;
};
console.log(validate({
  foo: {},
  bar: {},
  baz: {}
}));
console.log(validate({
  foo: {},
  bar: {},
  baz: {},
  buzz: {}
}));
```

Or, for an error message of the missing properties, maybe `filter` instead:

```js
const together = ['bar', 'baz', 'buzz'];
const validate = obj => {
  if (!obj.foo) return false;
  const missingProps = together.filter(prop => !(prop in obj));
  return (missingProps.length === 0 || missingProps.length === together.length)
    ? true
    : 'missing ' + missingProps.join(', ');
};
console.log(validate({
  foo: {},
  bar: {},
  baz: {}
}));
console.log(validate({
  foo: {},
  bar: {},
  baz: {},
  buzz: {}
}));
```